# Is there a way to get sha256 image digests from Argo CD API?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, argocd

I've explored Argo CD APIs from documentation, so far call to **/api/v1/applications** gives me images but without sha256 digests. Meaning I cannot be sure in exact version of the running image (say if the tag is set to latest or if there are multiple images per tag).

Same happened when I tried to use **/api/v1/applications/appname/resource-tree** or **/api/v1/applications/appname**.

Would appreciate if somebody could point me to some other call or way (maybe via cli) to retrieve sha256 digests of images (if that option exists).

**UPDATE:** Apparently it gives me sha256 if I explicitly add it in the spec, but if I use image without sha256, it wouldn't give me sha256 - wondering if there is an option for this case.

Comment: What is your end goal here? Argo just applies whatever you tell it. It doesn't really track versions itself for the most part.

Comment: Yes, I want to track versions of images for all deployed containers (it's also a security issue, not only versioning issue). I know how to do it using kubectl but I was wondering if I could get this from Argo API. 

End goal for me here - to obtain sha256 digest of each deployed image on k8s so I can match them against my metadata service and thus track state of the system. If such output could be scoped to Argo applications - even better.

If Argo does not support that - such knowledge would also be valuable information for me.

Comment: You would get that from the Kubernetes API, not Argo. Specifically look at `Pod.Status.ContainerStatuses[*].ImageID`. It has what you are looking for :)

Comment: @taleodor Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @OhHiMark as coderanger mention this does not seem possible with Argo. If you're looking for a kubectl way - I did it previously, mentioned in my blog here: https://worklifenotes.com/2020/01/25/kubernetes-list-all-deployed-images-with-sha256-hash/
Here is a sample script using this logic in my toy project - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-deployment/blob/master/send_instance_data_to_reliza.sh